# Android change drop down style in Spinner / add own icon on item selected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am customizing spinner in Android / Xamarin project. It's set to SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem. I would like to add icon which is with selected / default item. What I've already did with style is Spinner background (it's white and rounded), also there is style for background in drop down list.

## Spinner implementation

```
Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);

spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
        this, Resource.Array.organisation_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
spinner.SetSelection(1);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

## XML in Activity

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
style="@style/DropDownSpinner.My"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
```

## XML Styles

```
<style name="DropDownSpinner.My" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_spinner</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code work for you :

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

    spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position)
                              .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.favicone,0);
    // Reset the others 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a custom adapter with custom layout.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
```

you should have a special layout for selected item (layout with text and a start icon)

below is the **psudo code**

```
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt){

        ...
        int selected = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if(position == selected){
            return special layout with the start icon
        }
        return normal layout

    }
```